# Erro de sintaxe Access SQL para encontrar e excluir duplicatas deixando apenas uma

Tags: microsoft-access

Boa tarde pessoal.

Estou tentando fazer um código SQL exemplo que encontrei na Internet para encontrar as duplicatas da minha tabela do Access e deletar mantendo apenas o primeiro record. Porém, ao trocar todos campos onde dizia (Field1, Field2, ...) pelos nomes das colunas em si, começou dar erro de sintaxe. Antes quando estava os valores "Field", ele rodava e abria um prompt solicitando o nome de cada coluna. Segue o código:

```
DELETE *
FROM [Export Excel]
WHERE [Export Excel].ID IN


(SELECT F.ID
FROM [Export Excel] AS F
WHERE Exists (SELECT [Export Excel].[Criado em], [Export Excel].Encerrado, [Export Excel].Número, [Export Excel].Elemento Primário, [Export Excel].Descrição resumida, [Export Excel].Grupo designado, [Export Excel].Atribuído a, [Export Excel].Categoria, [Export Excel].Estado, Count(ID)
FROM [Export Excel]
WHERE [Export Excel].Criado em = F.Criado em
   AND [Export Excel].Encerrado = F.Encerrado
   AND [Export Excel].Número = F.Número
   AND [Export Excel].Elemento Primário = F.Elemento Primário
   AND [Export Excel].Descrição resumida = F.Descrição resumida
   AND [Export Excel].Grupo designado = F.Grupo designado
   AND [Export Excel].Atribuído a = F.Atribuído a
   AND [Export Excel].Categoria = F.Categoria
   AND [Export Excel].Estado = F.Estado
GROUP BY [Export Excel].Criado em, [Export Excel].Encerrado, [Export Excel].Número, [Export Excel].Elemento Primário, [Export Excel].Descrição resumida, [Export Excel].Grupo designado, [Export Excel].Atribuído a, [Export Excel].Categoria, [Export Excel].Estado
HAVING Count([Export Excel].ID) > 1))
AND [Export Excel].ID NOT IN


(SELECT Min(ID)
FROM [Export Excel] AS F
WHERE Exists (SELECT Criado em, Encerrado, Count(ID)
FROM [Export Excel]
WHERE [Export Excel].Criado em = F.Criado em
   AND [Export Excel].Encerrado = F.Encerrado
   AND [Export Excel].Número = F.Número
   AND [Export Excel].Elemento Primário = F.Elemento Primário
   AND [Export Excel].Descrição resumida = F.Descrição resumida
   AND [Export Excel].Grupo designado = F.Grupo designado
   AND [Export Excel].Atribuído a = F.Atribuído a
   AND [Export Excel].Categoria = F.Categoria
   AND [Export Excel].Estado = F.Estado
GROUP BY [Export Excel].Criado em, [Export Excel].Encerrado, [Export Excel].Número, [Export Excel].Elemento Primário, [Export Excel].Descrição resumida, [Export Excel].Grupo designado, [Export Excel].Atribuído a, [Export Excel].Categoria, [Export Excel].Estado
HAVING Count([Export Excel].ID) > 1)
GROUP BY Criado em, Encerrado);
```

Answer (score 0):

@Rodrigo BRF Os nomes dos campos que possuem espaços ou hífen devem ser colocados entre colchetes.

Exemplo: `F.[Criado em]`